# Am I violating AdSense TOS by allowing Google Translate widget to translate into unsupported languages?

Tags: google-adsense, language, google-translate

**DETAILS**

I want to use a Google Translate widget/plugin on my website. The website is written in English and has AdSense code embedded in it. The website is aimed at a global market, but because of the niche I expect them to use English. Despite that, I'd like to make translation available to all those who need it.

**QUESTION**

Am I violating adsense TOS by allowing google translate widget to translate into unsupported AdSense languages? Do I have to restrict the languages that can be translated to adsense supported languages only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up emailing Google.

**MY LETTER**

If my website is written in English, but I allow my visitors to
temporarily translate the page using the Google Translate tool, do I need to remove
unsupported adsense languages from the Google Translate tool? Since the
translation is a temporary one I assume that the language is primarily
in English and thus not in violation of AdSense TOS. Am I wrong?
Thanks for your time.

**THEIR RESPONSE**

Hi,

If the site is written in English, this will be fine.

**UPDATE**

I also posted this question on the Google Adsense forum.
User Luzie added that

> You'd violate the ToS if you'd let the search engines index automatic
>   translations (they're deemed low quality and a bad user experience if
>   presented as "content") - else I'd restrict ads to allowed languages.

**UPDATE2**

According to Google Translate Help https://support.google.com/translate/?hl=en

> The automatically translated version of your web page will not be
>   indexed by search engines